Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{\sin x\sin y(\cos x + \cos y)}}$
The answer seems to be
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right]^2$$
which I verified by numerically calculate it with Wolfram Mathematica
But cannot figure out how to do it analytically.
What I have tried:

Integrate by $x$ first, but this leads to complex result contains Gamma/Elliptic function, which blocks further integrate $y$;
Substitute variable $u=\tan x; v=\tan y$, $u=\tan x; v=\tan y$， hoping to convert the upper limit of integrate $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\infty$ then convert to polar coordinate, but there are $\sqrt{\sqrt{*}}$ on $u, v$ and I cannot see how to further process.

Anyone can help please? Thanks a lot!

What have you tried, aside from plugging into Mathematica? Are you familiar with the gamma/beta functions or elliptic integrals? Where did the integral come from?

I'm asking because I have no idea of how to start. Tried integrate by $x$ first but apparently it leads to complex  elliptic integrals which blocks further integrate by $y$. Also tried change variable $t=\tan x$/$t^2=\tan x$, but no luck. I only have basic knowledge of Gamma/Beta function, but one can learn if someone can point out a path to result.  The last question should be irrelevant. Where the integral comes from shouldn't change the way calculate it.

You're right, the exact source of the problem is not always crucial information. I was just trying to coax out any extra context whatsoever, and you delivered, so thanks! These are all details that should have been included in the body of your question. Notice the multiple vetoes to reopen for the same reason - your edits haven't made any significant changes to the content/quality of your post.

Anyway, a hint: trig sub is on the right track IMO, but try replacing both variables with tangent half-angles instead.

@user170231 So thanks a lot for the hint. I'll have a try.

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{dy\,dx}{\sqrt{\sin x \sin y (\cos x + \cos y)}} \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt2\,dv\,du}{\sqrt u\sqrt v\sqrt{1-u^2v^2}} & (x,y)=(2\arctan u,2\arctan v) \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt u} \frac{2\sqrt2\,dv\,du}{u\sqrt{1-v^4}} & v\to\frac{v^2}u \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_{v^2}^1 \frac{2\sqrt2\,du\,dv}{u\sqrt{1-v^4}} \\
&= -4\sqrt2 \int_0^1 \frac{\log v}{\sqrt{1-v^4}} \, dv \\
&= -\frac1{2\sqrt2} \int_0^1 \frac{\log v}{v^{3/4} \sqrt{1-v}} \, dv & v\to v^{1/4} \\
&= -\frac1{2\sqrt2} \lim_{a\to-3/4} \frac\partial{\partial a} \underbrace{\int_0^1 v^a (1-v)^{-1/2} \, dv}_{\operatorname{Beta}\left(\tfrac12,1+a\right)}
\end{align*}$$
This leads to some digamma expressions, and the overall result can be reduced by reflection formulae for the beta/gamma and polygamma functions:
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \operatorname{Beta}\left(\frac12,\frac14\right) \left[\psi\left(\frac34\right) - \psi\left(\frac14\right)\right] \\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)} \cdot \pi \cot\frac\pi4 \\
&= \frac\pi{2\sqrt2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt\pi \, \Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{\frac\pi{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)\sin\frac\pi4}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt\pi}4 \Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^2
\end{align*}$$
Incidentally, this result can also be expressed in terms of the complete elliptic integral of the first kind, $I = \pi\,K\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)$, although I do not immediately see the connection aside from the equivalent closed form.

Thanks a lot! This solves the problem.

On your last remark, found some interesting material https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html
